# How to show total number of windows using rad studio?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder

I am trying the code below in my cpp file and it's giving me the error:

> [bcc32 Error] Unit1.cpp(15): E2031 Cannot cast from 'int (**stdcall * (_closure )(HWND** *,long))(HWND__ *,long)' to 'int (**stdcall *)(HWND** *,long)'

What am I doing wrong?

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
: TForm(Owner)
{
    BOOL WINAPI EnumWindows((WNDENUMPROC) EnumWinProc, NULL);
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWinProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char title[80];
    GetWindowText(hwnd,title,sizeof(title));
    Listbox1->Items->Add(title);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shown cannot be your real code.  First, the syntax you are using to `EnumWindows()` is wrong and will not compile as-is.  Second, the error is complaining about casting a `__closure`, which means you are trying to use a non-static class method as the callback (which you cannot do), but there is no such method in the code you have shown.

This is what the code **should** look like:

```
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:
    TListBox *ListBox1;
    ...
private:
    static BOOL CALLBACK EnumWinProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam);
    ...
public:
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
    ...
};
```

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    EnumWindows(&EnumWinProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));
}

BOOL CALLBACK TForm1::EnumWinProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TCHAR title[80];
    if (GetWindowText(hwnd, title, 80))
        reinterpret_cast<TForm1*>(lParam)->ListBox1->Items->Add(title);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
// Note: NOT a member of the TForm1 class...
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWinProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TCHAR title[80];
    if (GetWindowText(hwnd, title, 80))
        reinterpret_cast<TStrings*>(lParam)->Add(title);
    return TRUE;
}

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    EnumWindows(&EnumWinProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(ListBox1->Items));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lose the `BOOL WINAPI`. You're trying to call a function, not declare one.

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
: TForm(Owner)
{
   EnumWindows((WNDENUMPROC) EnumWinProc, NULL);
}
```

Also, lose the unneccesary `(WNDENUMPROC)` conversion. Your callback func should have the correct signature, and if it doesn't, you want to know.